# How much of Anakin's love life during the war do we know?

Tags: star-wars, love

We see how quickly Anakin and Padme escalated in Ep II. What about during the Clone Wars? How much time do they get to spend together? Were they able to have a honeymoon, or spend any time on vacation or dates otherwise in general away from the public eye? Does being Force sensitive change relationship dynamics? Were there any ongoing story during the time when Anakin & Padme *ahem* conceived the twins?

The questions you think of when there's nothing to do in a bus...

Comment: Well, there was that one time he visited her in the Senate... he even gives her his lightsaber right there in her office (http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hostage_Crisis). Then there was the time she hooked up with her ex and made her hubby the jealous fuming driver/pilot/bodyguard (http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Senate_Spy). And the time he wanted a quiet evening at home... probably to look out the window at the startling Coruscant view, but she just *had* to have one of those senatorial parties (http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Evil_Plans)... so he went to her office the next day [see above]

Comment: Too much.     That would be my answer. But it's too short for this system

Comment: Duplicate of the one that asked when Luke and Leia were born (where the answer explicitly mentioned the honeymoon) IMHO

Comment: hmm but does it ask whether being a Force sensitive changes relationship dynamics?

Comment: @thegreatjedi - if you want THAT, you should split that into its own separate question (and not hang it on Anakin... he's not exactly a *normal* example)